# How to stop Visual Studio 2017 updating the solution version number

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 at work so I can use all the latest Xamarin goodness. Everyone else is using Visual Studio 2015.

I have been asked to work on a legacy project and opened the solution with 2017. This is causing problems for the other coders as 2017 changes the solution header version number and our old source control system (Source Vault) informs everyone their solution file is out of date.

Is there any way to get 2017 not to update the version number in the solution header so I can continue using 2017. It's so much faster than 2015.

For reference this is the header after I open the solution in 2017

```
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.27130.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

and this is it in 2015

```
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Comment: use source control and revert the sln change after using VS2017. older versions also do this, not only 2017